# Starting out, dissertation project using computer controlled drone

Tags: quadcopter, control, microcontroller, computer-vision

For my final year in Computer Science university I will be doing a dissertation that includes controlling a drone through computer and communication with an onboard camera for computer vision.

The first step is obtaining a drone that suits my needs, and I have no clue how to go about it. Basically what is needed is a drone that will be able to communicate with a computer both for its movement and to "stream" the video to the computer for analysis.

So, would I go for a store bought drone, a rasperry pi or some other microcontroller based one etc. What do I need to take into consideration etc?

P.S. the project is going to be based indoors, so I don't need crazy range, or very powerf

Comment: AR Drone is your choice. The price is affordable. You can access to two cameras and you can control your drone via PC by using their SDK. You need to know C and Makefiles.

Comment: @CroCo C I have some basic knowledge with c. What exactly is Makefiles? Also, why access to two cameras? I only see it having 1 in front.

Comment: the second is in the bottom if you want to access it but you don't have to. Makefiles are files that `make` program uses to generate the executable file for your app. This is because the SDK of this Drone is only compatible with Linux.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* MrUber, but I'm afraid that *[shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)* really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works, and the [*Robotics* question checklist](http://meta.robotics.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) for details of how to write a good question.

Comment: The things you'll need to take into consideration are the things you are interested in. This is probably cost, video format, open control interface, SDK language, update rates, quadcopter performance, battery life... the list goes on. As a final year student in a university, it's up to you to properly specify the requirements for what you need. Once you have that list of specifications, then it's just a matter of shopping/searching online until you find a model that meets all your specs. If you don't find an off-the-shelf unit that meets all of your needs, then you make one or edit your needs.